# Why is bitcoin balance is incorrect?

Tags: transactions

For bitcoin-QT, why can't I get any confirmations, but it still subtracts from my total balance?

Comment: please you need to be a bit more precise on describing your situation. We don't know what "it still subtracts" means, and also what confirmations you expect. Maybe a tx ID or bitcoin address would help, if you don't mind privacy.

Answer (score 0):

When you send from your wallet, your wallet will subtract the amount sent and mark the input that was spent as spent even when the transaction is unconfirmed. This is to prevent you from creating a conflicting transaction accidentally if you wish to send Bitcoin to someone else while the previous send is not confirmed.

This is standard behavior for all wallets.